# Does an adjacent Grass block affect growing wheat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do Grass blocks beside growing wheat affect its growth?

[image: Grass Block beside growing wheat]

Comment: Anecdotally no.

Comment: Grass adjacent to wheat can actually harm it, as pigs and sheep can spawn there and trample your crops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the [crop growth rate formula](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat_Farming#Growth_Rate) found on the wiki is correct: no.

The only blocks that can have a beneficial/detrimental effect on crop growth are other crops next to them.

Comment: Other crops, and water.

Comment: And the adjacent light level.

Answer (score 3):

No, grass blocks do not affect growing wheat.